# How to call a AWS Lambda outside of AWS

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

This is a quite basic question, but I was unable to find it out: How can I call a lambda via https without using an EC2 instance or something similar which has to run 24/7. So that I can call my method from an App, via CURL or what every tool which supports http.

I found some references to some Gateway APIs, but I don't know how to call them. Also do I need to setup some access permissions? Can I setup also access control or do I need to implement that within the lambda?

Comment: Usually you would want to invoke your Lambda function from API Gateway. Thus you'd want to create an API in API Gateway and connect it to your Lambda function. See [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html) for further details

Comment: @tesseract that was the reference I was looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it either with [API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html) or by [CLI](http://docs.amazonaws.cn/cli/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html) 
The API way will be time-consuming, but usually more robust and maintainable.

Comment: This answer is a little short, while the references are fine. The CLI is a great option in general, but not of my usecase (my fault). Regarding the API now I know the local part of the url and the possible headers and responses, but where is the domain? I cannot spot all parts I would need e.g. for a curl call.

Comment: In this case,  [this document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html)  will complete the answer. You will be able to use CURL as mentioned in the step 8.

Answer (score 2):

AWS doesn't care where your code is running, when you access its APIs.

The service endpoints are all accessible via the Internet.

There's nothing magical about accessing the APIs from "inside," because that isn't what you're doing, in the most logical sense, when you run code on EC2.

Technically speaking, the API requests *always* go out to the Internet.  If you are accessing an AWS service within the same AWS region, your requests still logically go out to the Internet, even though the traffic between your application and the API endpoint never actually leaves the AWS IP infrastructure... but if you have an EC2 instance that can't access the Internet, then it can't access the service API endpoints, either.

(One exception exists  if you have an S3 VPC endpoint configured, but this is something you have to configure, and it only allows access to S3 buckets within the same region).

The same code, without modification, should work from inside and outside.

Comment: How do I find out the URL of my lambda for e.g. my browser?

Comment: You didn't mention that you were invoking it from a browser.  "Your" Lambda function doesn't have a URL of its own, though the Lambda service endpoint (where requests are sent) does... but rather than play 20 questions here, I'd respectfully suggest that you edit your original question to describe *exactly* what you want to do, who will be doing it (You? Visitors to a web site?), and what the function's actual purpose is.  I assumed, as I believe @DamienM did, that you were talking about invoking functions from a local server, or your desktop or other workstation (not using the browser).

Comment: I modified my question. Since I was asking to invoke it via https I thought it would be clear enough. My exact usecase does not really matter out of my opinion, since I just want to execute my *cloud* code. It does not matter if it switches a lamp on, does some online banking or starts a process to buy a new TV. Based on that a browser should be the simplest http client. However the connection could be not trustworthy, so I need to make sure that nobody will buy 1k TVs per day :-)

Comment: I didn't mean *exactly* what it can do.  I just wanted to try to get enough information to clarify.  The comment from @tesseract is on the right track -- you *build* a custom HTTPS API endpoint for your specific functions using [Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/).  "Invoke it via HTTPS" did not imply to me that it would be a browser or untrusted, because all interactions with all AWS services [are done over http(s)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) and I thought you were asking how to call these with code running somewhere other than EC2.

Answer (score 1):

You can also assign a dedicated URL directly to your Lambda without having to use the API Gateway.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-invocation.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume you connected your API Gateway with your Lambda and the test invocation works as expected. The final step you are missing is the deployment. You have to deploy your API Gateway in order to invoke it from outside. In the API Gateway sections, you click on the "Actions" button and then on "Deploy API". After the deployment, you will receive an URL which you can call via CURL to invoke your Lambda. 
I hope that helps you further.

Comment: What about authentication/authorization? The endpoint should be protected. It means that incoming HTTP requests should contain some token. Who will be responsible for generating this token?